# How can I put an equals sign in a GKeyFile key name?

Tags: glib

I'm using [GKeyFile](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html) to store configuration. I need to store a dictionary of URLs to boolean values. URLs are strings, so .

GKeyFile seemed like a good fit, but some of my URLs have equals signs in them, e.g. http://example.com?x=y

This doesn't work, because the first equal sign is interpreted as the key/value separator.

```
[Links]
http://example.com?x=y=true
```

Escaping the equal sign doesn't seem to help either.

```
[Links]
http://example.com?x\=y=true
```

Is there any way to do what I want in a GKeyFile file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s02.html#entries):

> Only the characters `A-Za-z0-9-` may be used in key names.

Comment: That's regrettable. GKeyFile does happen to support other characters, e.g. the slashes work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to work around this (at the cost of human-readability) is to encode your URIs when writing them, e.g., using `g_base64_encode`, and doing the reverse when reading them.

Comment: Base64 wouldn't work, because it allows equals signs in the output.